# Sync push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have question about push notification sync between devices.

I'm building application for iPhone and iPad.
Both of them support push notifications and I send notifications to both devices at the same time.

Is it possible to "hide/dismiss" the push notification on all devices (or change  badge) when the notification is opened? Like iMessages.

On io7 slide features 'Notification sync' is enabled on third party application

Thanks.

Comment: I found this [link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/844534#844534) 
seems to do it automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can change the badge value in the app delegate by using the function

```
applicationDidReceivedRemoteNotification:
```

Check UIApplication for more reference.

Comment: This method is call when the notification is received.
But the my question is different.
Is it possible to "hide/dismiss" the push notification on all devices when the notification is opened.
For example i received notification on my iphone and my ipad, i open a notification on iphone and on ipad dismiss a notification.

Comment: No that is not possible.